# Swift extension "Method definition not found"

Tags: objective-c, swift

**I'm writing a Swift extension to my ObjC class.** Although my code compiles and runs perfectly, **I'm getting a bunch of Xcode warnings** (one per every Swift method):

```
  "Method definition for 'foo_method:' not found"
  "Method definition for 'bar_method:' not found"
  "Method definition for 'baz_method:' not found"
```

---

It's dead simple to reproduce the Xcode message. I made this demo project with four lines of non-boilerplate code:

Objective-C (subclass of NSView)

```
// Subclass_of_NSView.h

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h

@interface Subclass_of_NSView : NSView

@end


// Subclass_of_NSView.m

@implementation Subclass_of_NSView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
//______________^ WARNING: Method definition for resizeSubviewsWithOldSize: not found
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Swift (extends the Obj-C subclass)

```
// Extension_of_Subclass.swift

import Foundation

extension Subclass_of_NSView {

    override func resizeSubviewsWithOldSize( old_bounds_size:NSSize ) {

    }

}
```

Bridging-Header

```
// Demo_Project-Bridging-Header.h

#import "Subclass_of_NSView.h"
```

---

I'm guessing the warnings would go away if I either:

a) create a bunch of dummy methods in the .m file of my ObjC class.

b) in my Swift extension, extend my ObjC class's superclass.

I don't love either of these solutions.

**Is there a better way to make the compiler happy?**

Comment: You should post some code I think

Comment: I took some screenshots. The code on its own would probably be confusing since there's potentially 4 files involved.

Comment: I think it's a bug that should be reported

Comment: I did everything you said and couldn't reproduce the problem: the little demo app compiles just fine with no warnings.

Comment: @matt, it compiles without actual *errors* maybe, but neither machine upon which I have tried (and neither of two different projects) compile without *warnings*. I can run my app, but it's distracting to see dozens of warnings - especially if there's a legitimate warning hiding along with them.

Comment: But my point is that you are not giving enough information. I should be able to get exactly the same result you get. Give enough information so that I can do that!

Comment: However, I should add - I have not had _any_ luck adding a Swift extension to my own Objective-C classes. It is much easier just to translate the whole darned class into Swift - which, of course, is maddening, because you often can't really test until you've done the whole thing, which can take days.

Comment: @matt It's weird that extensions aren't working for you. It just requires A) “ #import "FOOBARCLASS.h" ” in the bridging header file B) “ #import "FOOBARAPP-Swift.h" ” in your ObjC .m file, and C) “ extension FOOBARCLASS {} ” in a .swift file, within which you add your new methods

Comment: @Charlesism Yeah, you'd think so, but that's not what I've found in practice. I've now translated a bunch of apps from Objective-C into Swift, and at no time has translating half a class at a time into an extension worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on here, I think the problem is something to do with how `NSView` is bridged to the swift language.

If you're going to override those methods, make sure you call the `super` implementation, since `NSView` will probably break spectacularly without them. However I'm not sure if even this is safe, you might still break `NSView` — perhaps the reason the errors occur is because of some weird/non-standard setup Apple is doing.

If I was you, I'd just put up with the compiler warnings, and report the issue to Apple via `http://bugreport.apple.com`. Hopefully it will be fixed in a future beta release of Xcode 6.

Comment: I downloaded the latest dev preview. Apple fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I am still seeing this problem with Xcode 7.3.1.

The reason why I cannot see the public function that is defined in the Objctive-C is because **I didn't include all the class in the parameters in the bridge header**. See the following example for more details:

I have class defined in Objective-C, like such:

**Foo.h**

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
- (void)function1;
- (void)function2:(Bar *)para; // here Bar is just another object
@end
```

**Foo.m**

```
@implementation Foo
// ...
@end
```

And in my bridge header I have `#import "Foo.h"` but not `#import "Bar.h"`. As a result, I can call `function1` from my swift extension but not `function2`.

**Foo.swift**

```
extension Foo {
    func function3() {
         function1(); // Okay
         function2(nil); // Method definition not found
    }
}
```

So, adding `#import "Bar.h"` to the bridge header solves the problem.